Flask-Login with 2 Tables
On my website, I need two tables for two types of users: Patients and Psychologists. Can I use Flask-Login for these two tables so I can manage logins for both Patients and Psychologists? Initially, I started with a single table of users with a column for the role, but the issue arose when the Appointments table referenced two foreign keys to the same users table for psychologist_id and patient_id. What should I do in this case?
I tried using one table, but it didn't work because the foreign keys were associated with the same table.

Can you share your models?
